# Парсинг чата твитча

Tags: php, node.js, framework

API чата Twitch.tv я достал. Суть вопроса как реализуется парсинг сайтов/чата, где можно о парсинге в общем прочитать в том числе, какие технологии нужно использовать?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь переписать вопрос так, чтобы его суть была понятна не только вам. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] сразу под текстом вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Поправил, слишком много текста написал. Извините.

Comment: увы, в текущем виде у вас получился [вопрос-опросник](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), и, с большой вероятностью, он будет закрыт. попробуйте внести больше конкретики: например, что именно у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для php есть хорошая библиотека [парсинга](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) попробуйте использовать ее, на сайте есть примеры. [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/72702/) статья на хабре про парсинг.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).